# Vectorizing three nested loops - NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have two arrays `x.dim = (N,4)` and `y.dim = (M, M, 2)` and a function `f(a, b)`, which takes `K` and `L`dimensional vectors respectively as arguments. I want to obtain an array `res.dim = (N, M, M)` such that

```
for n in range(N):
  for i in range(M):
    for j in range(M):
      res[n, i, j] = f(x[n], y[i, j])
```

Can't get how to use `apply` in this case. Thanks in advance for help!

```
def f(a, b):
    return max(0, 1 - np.sum(np.square(np.divide(np.subtract(b, a[0:2]), a[2:4]))))
```

Comment: this can not work, `i, j in range(N)` ? int object is not iterable? supposing range(N) is list of ints from 0 to N-1

Comment: Well then you write it how it's in practice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach to work with the listed function using [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and slicing -

```
# Slice out relevant cols from x
x_slice1 = x[:,None,None,:2]
x_slice2 = x[:,None,None,2:4]

# Perform operations using those slices to correspond to iterative operations
out = np.maximum(0,1-(np.divide(y-x_slice1,x_slice2)**2).sum(3))
```